# Image magician and PNG uploads

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have a problem with GD when trying to upload png. The error which I've got is

```
Warning: imagepng(): gd-png error: compression level must be 0 through 9... on line 2474
```

on line 2474 in `php_image_magician.php` is case for png

```
            case '.png':
    // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
    $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

    // *** Invert qualit setting as 0 is best, not 9
    $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

    $this->checkInterlaceImage($this->isInterlace);
    if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
       imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
    } else { $error = 'png'; }
            break;
```

and more specifically this

```
imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
```

There is no errors while I upload `jpg` images..

Here is in my upload file where is the problem

```
  $magicianObj = new imageLib($filepath);
  $magicianObj->resizeImage(300, 300);
  $magicianObj->saveImage($folderName . 'thumb/' . $filename, 300);
```

When I resize them,.

Comment: Why have you tagged this thread with Imagemagick when it has nothing to do with imagemagick? Do you have problems with other png images? Have you tried this image with other software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rereading your post again it looks like you are having problems with all png files. What value are you using for the png image quality as this line recalculates it:

```
$scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);
```

If you use an image quality in you code of 9 it will be changed to 0.81

Then again this line

`$invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;`

would convert the 0.81 to 8.19

Anyway I guess the problem is in the php file and not GD. I would echo some of the code out to see what values are being passed to the GD code.

You could also try hardcoding $invertScaleQuality to a value between 0 and 9 to see if that works.

Comment: Hardoced `$invertScaleQuality = 9;` and seems it's working perfectly. Thank's